# What is syscall-template.S?

Tags: kernel, c, glibc

I've come across a file `syscall-template.S` more specifically its location is

`.../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S`

1. What is this file?
2. Where is it. It is not on my system and I cannot find it in source packages, including `linux-image` and `glibc`.

Comment: You've come across it, but it's not on your system.  Where did you come across it?

Comment: http://autobuilder.pokylinux.org/sources/svn/www.eglibc.org/svn/branches/eglibc-2_12/libc/sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S ?

Answer (score 6):

It is a file that is necessary when you are compiling `C` code. Below you will see a snippet from building `glibc-2.14.1`

I was building a new LFS system today and just saw it fly by.

Guessing that it is related to `C` and provides `system call` info for building `C` programs with `gcc`

```
 echo '#define SYSCALL_SYMBOL __GI_mq_setattr'; \
Â echo '#include <syscall-template.S>'; \     <========### syscall-template.S
Â echo 'weak_alias (__GI_mq_setattr, mq_setattr)'; \
Â echo 'libc_hidden_weak (mq_setattr)'; \
) | x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc -cÂ  -I../include -I/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/rt -I/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build -I../sysdeps/x86_64/elf -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64 -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64 -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64 -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../nptl/sysdeps/pthread -I..
```

**EDIT:**

You don't see it because it is part of the `glibc` source.
located in:

`glibc-2.14.1/sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S`

This directory is typically deleted when you are finished installing.

**EDIT 2:**

I just reread your initial post. You said that it is not in the `glibc source` I wanted to verify and just extracted the `tar` again and it is in the path I listed above.